# Covering protruding bolts in a chairleg

Tags: repair, furniture

Some rubber feet came off of my chair's legs, exposing bolts that are digging holes in my carpet.

[image]

I used a temporary solution of just lashing some kitchen sponges onto area with rubber bands, but the bolts dug through those in a week or so. What can I do? Is there a (cheap) product available for this kind of situation, like a hard-drying rubber or silicone putty or something?

I tried just removing the bolts but they wouldn't budge or unscrew. The metal is very soft so I suppose I could just saw and sand them, but I'm looking for second opinions.

Comment: The difference between a cheap repair and a good repair isn't going to be that big I think.

Comment: What did the original feet look like? If there are any left on another chair, please post a pic of that too showing the bottom and side of the pad.

Comment: @Jack They were essentially rubber or plastic sleeves that wrapped around the corner of the leg seen in the picture. The bolts ended up digging through them after three or four years of use and they split in half and fell off. I don't have any pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bolts no longer serve a purpose, so cut them off (using bolt cutters, hack-saw, angle grinder, etc.).

If you want the chairs to have some sort of pads then buy and attach new ones. 
 You can get self-adhesive, or pads designed to attach with screws, bolts, rivets, etc.

Comment: The metal will probably be jagged and dangerous after I cut it. What sort of tool should I use to smooth it? Will sandpaper work?

Comment: @JackM yes you can use sandpaper to smooth it, although it would be a lot easier to use a grinding wheel on a Dremel.  We can't tell from the picture, but if they are riveted from the other side of the chair tube you could drill the expanded part so they come out completely.

Comment: A dremel with a cutting disk is a good solution. Once the majority is cut away, it may be possible to hammer the rest into the tube and more easily seal off the hole. Some rattle is to be expected, unless you apply glue to the pieces hammered in, prior to knocking them inside.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an epoxy ribbon material at someplace like Walmart or a hardware store. You mix the two strips of epoxy/hardener together and mold it how you like. You only want to mix enough at a time to do 1 bolt, as it starts hardening fairly fast, but not instantly, so you do have time to work with it. If you haven't used it before, then you'll want to pull off 2 small equal sized pieces to practice first. Good luck!